# Can you display a feed from an Instagram location?

Tags: feeds, instagram

I have found that a number of Instagram users have been posting images to a location rather than a business' Instagram handle, and would like to display a feed on a website (so external to Instagram) based on location rather than Instagram account name. But I can't find any information on locations within Instagram, if they can be in a feed, how to display location info from Instagram on a website, etc.

Does anyone have any experience with this or can point me in the right direction?